# How to use Drag and drop to move a Composable

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-jetpack-compose

Loosely following what I found for more common scenarios, for example [here](https://blog.canopas.com/android-drag-and-drop-ui-element-in-jetpack-compose-14922073b3f1), I'm trying to use Drag and Drop to allow the user to move an image on the screen.
It's a legacy app so I had to use a Fragment but this's irrelevant for the issue.

```
class DAndDFragment : Fragment() {
    private val viewModel by viewModels<DAndDViewModel>()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)

            setContent {
                val pip by viewModel.pip.collectAsState()

                AppTheme {                    DragAndDrop(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                        Dragged(
                            modifier = Modifier.offset(
                                pip.pos.x.dp, pip.pos.y.dp
                            ),
                            onDropped = { position ->
                                viewModel.pos(position.x, position.y)
                            }
                        ) {
                            Box(modifier = Modifier.size(pip.size.dp)) {
                                Image(
                                    painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(pip.image),
                                    contentDescription = null,
                                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                                    modifier = Modifier
                                        .size(pip.size.dp)
                                        .clip(appRoundedCornerShape())
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun Dragged(
        modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
        onDropped: (Offset) -> Unit,
        content: @Composable (Boolean) -> Unit
    ) {
        var currentPosition by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }
        val currentState = LocalDragTargetInfo.current
        Box(modifier = modifier
            .onGloballyPositioned {
                currentPosition = it.localToWindow(Offset.Zero)
            }
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectDragGesturesAfterLongPress(onDragStart = {
                    currentState.isDragging = true
                    currentState.position = currentPosition + it
                    currentState.draggableComposable = content
                }, onDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
                    change.consume()
                    currentState.offset += dragAmount
                }, onDragEnd = {
                    currentState.isDragging = false
                    currentState.position += currentState.offset
                    onDropped(currentState.position)
                    currentState.offset = Offset.Zero
                }, onDragCancel = {
                    currentState.offset = Offset.Zero
                    currentState.isDragging = false
                })
            }) {
            content(currentState.isDragging)
        }
    }
}

internal class DragTargetInfo {
    var isDragging: Boolean by mutableStateOf(false)
    var position: Offset by mutableStateOf(Offset(0f, 0f))
    var offset: Offset by mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero)
    var draggableComposable by mutableStateOf<(@Composable (Boolean) -> Unit)>({ })
}

internal val LocalDragTargetInfo = compositionLocalOf { DragTargetInfo() }

@Composable
fun DragAndDrop(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable BoxScope.() -> Unit
) {
    val state = remember { DragTargetInfo() }
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalDragTargetInfo provides state
    ) {
        Box(modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize())
        {
            content()
            if (state.isDragging) {
                var targetSize by remember {
                    mutableStateOf(IntSize.Zero)
                }
                Box(modifier = Modifier
                    .graphicsLayer {
                        val offset = state.position + state.offset
                        alpha = if (targetSize == IntSize.Zero) 0f else .5f
                        translationX = offset.x.minus(targetSize.width / 2)
                        translationY = offset.y.minus(targetSize.height / 2)
                    }
                    .onGloballyPositioned {
                        targetSize = it.size
                    }
                ) {
                    state.draggableComposable(true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything seems to be working fine until the user drops the dragged image.
The app gets a call to `onDragEnd` and I update the position of the image calling a callback and passing the offset and I calculate as:

```
currentState.position += currentState.offset
onDropped(currentState.position)
```

Please notice that I'm already using the same method to show the dragged image when I do:

```
val offset = state.position + state.offset
```

in the `DragAndDrop` Composable function where it works fine and it shows the dragged image properly.

Answer (score 0):

OK so two changes fixed the issue:

```
class DAndDFragment : Fragment() {
    private val viewModel by viewModels<DAndDViewModel>()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)

            setContent {
                val pip by viewModel.pip.collectAsState()

                AppTheme {
                    DragAndDrop(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                        Dragged(
                            modifier = Modifier.graphicsLayer {
                                translationX = pip.pos.x
                                translationY = pip.pos.y
                            },
                            onDropped = { position ->
                                viewModel.pos(position.x, position.y)
                            }
                        ) {
                            Box(modifier = Modifier.size(pip.size.dp)) {
                                Draggable(
                                    onVideoObject = pip
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun Draggable(
        onVideoObject: OnVideoObject
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(onVideoObject.image),
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(onVideoObject.size.dp)
                .clip(appRoundedCornerShape())
        )
    }
    @Composable
    fun Dragged(
        modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
        onDropped: (Offset) -> Unit,
        content: @Composable (Boolean) -> Unit
    ) {
        var currentPosition by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }
        val currentState = LocalDragTargetInfo.current
        Box(modifier = modifier
            .onGloballyPositioned {
                currentPosition = it.localToWindow(Offset.Zero)
            }
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectDragGesturesAfterLongPress(onDragStart = {
                    currentState.isDragging = true
                    currentState.position = currentPosition + it
                    currentState.draggableComposable = content
                }, onDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
                    change.consume()
                    currentState.offset += dragAmount
                }, onDragEnd = {
                    currentState.isDragging = false
                    currentState.position += currentState.offset
                    onDropped(currentState.position)
                    currentState.offset = Offset.Zero
                }, onDragCancel = {
                    currentState.offset = Offset.Zero
                    currentState.isDragging = false
                })
            }) {
            content(currentState.isDragging)
        }
    }
}

internal class DragTargetInfo {
    var isDragging: Boolean by mutableStateOf(false)
    var position: Offset by mutableStateOf(Offset(0f, 0f))
    var offset: Offset by mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero)
    var draggableComposable by mutableStateOf<(@Composable (Boolean) -> Unit)>({ })
}

internal val LocalDragTargetInfo = compositionLocalOf { DragTargetInfo() }

@Composable
fun DragAndDrop(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable BoxScope.() -> Unit
) {
    val state = remember { DragTargetInfo() }
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalDragTargetInfo provides state
    ) {
        Box(modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize())
        {
            content()
            if (state.isDragging) {
                var targetSize by remember {
                    mutableStateOf(IntSize.Zero)
                }
                Box(modifier = Modifier
                    .graphicsLayer {
                        val offset = state.position + state.offset
                        alpha = if (targetSize == IntSize.Zero) 0f else .5f
                        translationX = offset.x
                        translationY = offset.y
                    }
                    .onGloballyPositioned {
                        targetSize = it.size
                    }
                ) {
                    state.draggableComposable(true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So first of all I used

```
Modifier.graphicsLayer {
   translationX = pip.pos.x
   translationY = pip.pos.y
}
```

instead of the `Modifier.offset` as I was already doing in the `DragAndDrop` function where it was working.
I have also removed the `.minus(targetSize.width / 2)` and `.minus(targetSize.height / 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the new native (`implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.01.00')`) drag and drop functionality.

Here's a demo example of how you can work with drag and drop:

```
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(60.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(Color.Yellow)
            .dragAndDropSource {
                detectTapGestures(
                    onLongPress = {
                        startTransfer(
                            DragAndDropTransferData(
                                ClipData(
                                    "",
                                    arrayOf("array of mimeTypes - those tell dragAndDropTargets which type of dragAndDropSource this is, such as an image, text, phone number, or your custom type"),
                                    ClipData.Item("you can add new clip items with data here")
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    }
                )
            },
        color = Color.Black,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        text = "Hold me to drag and drop"
    )
    val enteredIndex = remember {
        mutableIntStateOf(-1)
    }

    LazyColumn {
        items(50) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .then(
                        if (enteredIndex.intValue == it) {
                            Modifier.background(Color.White)
                        } else Modifier.background(Color.Cyan)
                    )
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(80.dp)
                    .dragAndDropTarget(
                        shouldStartDragAndDrop = {
                            true
                        },
                        target = object : DragAndDropTarget {
                            override fun onDrop(event: DragAndDropEvent): Boolean {
                                enteredIndex.intValue = -1
                                return true
                            }
                            override fun onEntered(event: DragAndDropEvent) {
                                super.onEntered(event)
                                enteredIndex.intValue = it
                            }
                            override fun onExited(event: DragAndDropEvent) {
                                super.onExited(event)
                                enteredIndex.intValue = -1
                            }
                        }
                    ),
                color = Color.Black,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                text = "Content $it, that responds to drag and drop"
            )
        }
    }
```

Personally, I find good use of the drag and drop, as you can show the user where he's putting the item, and you can also draw either custom `dragAndDropSource` to visualize what the user is holding or *Compose* does it for you. You can also expand colorful `Boxes` as spaces where user can put items.

See more here: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2024/01/whats-new-in-jetpack-compose-january-24-release.html